# Not scraping website data with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

It is the 3rd or 4th time that I am using BeautifulSoup. I am using it alongside requests lib to scrape data from a [sports' website](https://ehfcl.eurohandball.com/men/2021-22/player/LFpFsiLDFvxs_tXnKlFAQw/luis-frade/). I am trying to scrape athletes' info such as name, age, height, etc. However, when trying to get the info(print(player_name)) I am getting this instead of what is displayed in the website page:

Name:{{details.player.person.lastName}}, {{details.player.person.firstName}}

Is there any way of accessing the real data?

My code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_player(player_url):

    response_player = requests.get(player_url)
    player_soup = BeautifulSoup(response_player.text, 'html.parser')
    div = player_soup.find('div', {'class' : 'player-info-row'})
    player_name = div.text
    print(player_name)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
     scrape_player('https://ehfcl.eurohandball.com/men/20212/player/LFpFsiLDFvxs_tXnKlFAQw/luis-frade/')
```

Comment: Hey @Duarte Guerreiro Welcome to SO! please edit your question with code so it will be easy to understand!

Comment: I am not able to open URL it is showing 404 for me!

Comment: What about this one? :
https://ehfcl.eurohandball.com/men/2021-22/player/Z8PG_QqFxhA-6PTQ4gcCSA/stas-skube/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website loads data from script tags so its dynamic loaded and `bs4` will not able to caputer via tags or class but although it is present in `script` tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://ehfcl.eurohandball.com/men/2021-22/player/Z8PG_QqFxhA-6PTQ4gcCSA/stas-skube/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

Here we can find `script` tag and load data into json format which returns data as key value pair and you can extract what so data you want!

```
data=soup.find("script",attrs={"type":"application/ld+json"})

import json
main_data=json.loads(data.string)

print(main_data['name'])
print(main_data['birthDate'])
```

Output:

```
Skube Stas
1989-11-15
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I never used json functions with BeautifulSoup when scraping but it was interesting to find what it can do. The only problem when running was that I got : NameError: name 'headers' is not defined. But as soon as I removed "headers = headers" it worked just fine. Thank you again!

Comment: you can remove it, just typo mistake!